# Http request two container each other with one nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I can not use curl to communicate between curator and dispenser container.
I want to access from curator container like curl http://dispenser.shadysmaoui.test.
these two container, I can request by http request from host normally.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./apps/curator/:/var/www/curator
      - ./apps/dispenser/:/var/www/dispenser
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./docker/nginx/sites/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
      - ./docker/nginx/ssl/:/etc/ssl/
    networks:
      - app-network

  curator:
    build:
      context: apps/curator
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: curator
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www/curator
    volumes:
      - ./apps/curator/:/var/www/curator
      - ./docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  dispenser:
    build:
      context: apps/dispenser
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: dispenser
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www/dispenser
    volumes:
      - ./apps/dispenser/:/var/www/dispenser
      - ./docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

Answer (score 1):

Between containers use the service name : `curl http://webserver` or `https://webserver`

Comment: Almost work but if I request to curl http://webserver from whichever container, it always to go Curator container.

Comment: that problem not yet fixed. any idea? @Sébastien Helbert

Comment: Double check your nginx configuration, it may be incorrect. 
Otherwise, why do you not access directly to dispenser via http://dispenser ?